# Mass export files from Chatter Feed and Chatter Comments

Tags: chatter, chatter-file, feedcomment

How to mass export files from  chatter feed and chatter comments.I looked into the reviews of  [file exporter app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003Iz0jEAC) but it looks like it is not supporting chatter attachments.Is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API to accomplish part of this. For files that are attached to feed items, you can query the [FeedItem SObject](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) for ContentData where the Type = ContentPost.

Unfortunately, files attached to comments aren't supported in the SObject API. They're supported in the Chatter REST API and Chatter in Apex, but you wouldn't be able to do a mass export because those APIs can only run as the current, logged-in user. They're not data APIs.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the chatter posts and document record id's in bulk through the rest and soap API by querying the [feeditem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm) and [feed attachment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedattachment.htm)
then after this you can loop over your list of feedattachments and retrieve the contentDocuments and the files in them 1 by 1 in base64 format through scripting.

the final step would then be to decode the base64 strings and store the documents again with the correct filenames on your local system.

keep in mind when doing such exports that you need to have sufficient data storage and memory allocated to the system performing these exports, hence why you will also need to retrieve documents 1 by 1 to avoid errors